# Hibernate criteria list iterating

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, iterator

I have the following section of code that I want to use to return a collection of my object:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

List<MyObj> myObjList = (List<MyObj>) 
        session.createCriteria(MyObj.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("searchField", searchField)).list();

Iterator<MyObj> myObjIt = myObjList.listIterator();
log.debug("list size: " + myObjList.size());

while(myObjIt.hasNext()){
    MyObj myObj = myObjIt.next();
    log.debug(myObj.getMyField());

}
```

However, my log keeps printing the same record as many times as the size of the list.  If I refactor slightly, my code works correctly like this:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "select my_field from my_table where search_field = :searchField"
    );

query.setParameter("myField", myField);
List result = query.list();
for(Iterator iter = result.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
    Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();
    log.debug(row[0]);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in my first code segment? I should be able to go about this either way, and since I'm using Hibernate, I'd rather the ORM be working as expected, so I'd prefer the former method over the latter.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Fwiw, I am using Hibernate 3.5.4 final, Hibernate-validator 4.2.0 Final, hibernate-search 3.4.0 Final, and hibername-c3p0 3.6.5 final, all from the maven repos.

**Edited to clarify based on comments.**

Comment: Do not understand what you expect the 'correct' behavior to be.  If you query every object where name = 'Joe';  and it returns 100 objects.  Then if you iterate over them and print name, what else do y ou expect to see but 'Joe' 100 times?

Comment: Sorry.  I clarified.  I am searching on one field that will have a value occur many times, and am looking for the other field's values.  That got lost when I was obscuring what I was doing a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described in the question, your both code segments should return the same results. Assuming that in first code segment Hibernate executes pretty the same query as in second segment (you can check it in log, just enable 'hibernate.show_sql' config parameter) - problem is somewhere in converting result set to MyObj list. It is pretty unlikely that it happens due to a bug in hibernate, so it can be due to incorrect entity class mapping. If you do not see any problems with mapping, please add more details to the question (your entity class with mappings, db table schema and data sample) so anyone can reproduce the issue.

Likely your MyObj class does not have Id column mapping properly defined. For example if the field/property mapped as Id has the same value for all the objects in the result list, hibernate will return same objects (as in your case).
Regarding using primitives as Id type: hibernate allow using primitive types, but it has the following line in the docs:

> We recommend that you declare consistently-named identifier properties on persistent classes and that you use a nullable (i.e., non-primitive) type.

Summarizing possible Id mapping issues:
1. Id mapped column is not unique in db.
2. Corresponding setter  for Id property getter mapped is not specified or does not really save passed argument value.
3. Not-nullable type of Id field.

Comment: I do have an ID set for that object (using annotations).

Comment: @dmcnelis That field mapped as Id, is it unique? I mean, does the following query return different 'my_id' for each row: 'select my_id, my_field from my_table where search_field = :searchField'

Comment: Yes, it does, the field mapped to to 'my_id' is the primary key for the field.  It is declared in my code as @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="my_id")
protected int myId;

Comment: Sorry moved down here from the original question...      
How about adding, log.debug(myObj.getId() + "/" +myObj.getMyField()); to ensure you are getting either the same or different rows back ... not the full answer but might help provoke my ideas about what may be happening

Comment: It keeps returning an id of 0. The minimum id in the table is 1

Comment: That is interesting ... but not sparked any ideas from me. I would agree that its probably a mapping issue. How about putting your either MyObj class up in the question, and xml mapping if your using that?

Comment: @dmcnelis does you id property have a setter?

Comment: @dmcnelis Try changing Id property type from int to Integer. Hibernate checks Id for null to identify if entity is transient.